# file.copy in R not working

Tags: r

I am using the command file.copy in R and it throws an error, but I can't spot the reason.

```
 file.copy(from="Z:/Ongoing/Test", to = "C:/Users/Darius/Desktop", overwrite = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

 Warning message:
 In file.copy(from = "Z:/Ongoing/Test",:
 problem copying Z:/Ongoing/Test to C:/Users/Darius/Desktop/Test: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone see the problem? The command line doesn't work even though it only gives you a warning message.

Comment: Well, are you sure the source path is valid? Does the file exist?

Comment: `Z:/Ongoing/Test` is a file or directory? Is there a file and directory called "test" ?

Comment: What does list.files("Z:/Ongoing/" return? Is there a file named (exacly) "Test"? I suspect there might be a file named "test.doc" or "Test.xlsx"
 and you think it is named "Test" because of your file browser hiding data.

Comment: It is a whole directory (folder) called test where I have put some files. I want the whole directory with its contents to be copied to the "to" location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I don't think there is any straight forward way to copy a directory. I have written a function which might help you.

This function takes input two arguments:

from: The complete path of directory to be copied

to: The location to which the directory is to be copied

**Assumption: from and to are paths of only one directory.**

```
dir.copy <- function(from, to){

  ## check if from and to directories are valid
  if (!dir.exists(from)){
    cat('from: No such Directory\n')
    return (FALSE)
  }
  else if (!dir.exists(to)){
    cat('to: No such Directory\n')
    return (FALSE)
  }

  ## extract the directory name from 'from'
  split_ans <- unlist(strsplit(from,'/'))

  dir_name <- split_ans[length(split_ans)]

  new_to <- paste(to,dir_name,sep='/')

  ## create the directory in 'to'
  dir.create(new_to)

  ## copy all files in 'to'
  file_inside <- list.files(from,full.names = T)

  file.copy(from = file_inside,to=new_to)

  ## copy all subdirectories
  dir_inside <- list.dirs(path=from,recursive = F)

  if (length(dir_inside) > 0){
    for (dir_name in dir_inside)
      dir.copy(dir_name,new_to)
  }

  return (TRUE)
}
```

Comment: It is not a file but a whole folder called "test". So what I am looking for is to copy the whole folder and the files in it to the new location.

Comment: @Stibu At the moment the question was posted, the question was not clear. Now, I have edited the solution to match the requirements.

Comment: Thanks @KunalPuri. That was a great answer and it works incredible well.

Comment: This seems to do the work of the file.copy recursive argument

Answer (score 3):

The `file.copy()` doesn't create directories. So it'll only work if you're copying to folders that already exist.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar issue:

This [blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/11/copying-files-with-r/) was helpful. Slightly modified the code by adding `full.names=T` and `overwrite = T`.

```
current.folder <- "E:/ProjectDirectory/Data/"
new.folder <- "E:/ProjectDirectory/NewData/"
list.of.files <- list.files(current.folder, full.names = T)
# copy the files to the new folder
file.copy(list.of.files, new.folder, overwrite = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that worked best for me. This takes every file/folder in a parent directory and clones it to another directory, with an optional overwrite argument.

```
clone_dir <- function(from,to,overwrite=F){
  for(FOLDER in list.files(from,full.names = T)){
    file.copy(
      from = FOLDER,
      to = to,
      recursive = T,
      overwrite = overwrite
    )
  }
} 

clone_dir(
  from = "your/parent/dir",
  to = "your/cloned/dir",
  overwrite = F
)
```

I like this better than the default R way which normally adds the "from" directory folder inside of the "to" directory.

```
file.copy(
  from = "your/parent/dir",
  to = "your/cloned/dir",
  recursive = T,
  overwrite = F
)
```